# Gcc expert 24 vinyl cutter

Tags: peripherals

my friend had a gift: Gcc expert 24 vinyl cutter without drivers installation cd or serial cable, only usb cable and power chord.
Itryed with inkscape/inkcut and everythings looks fine but the "plotter" doesen't respond.
Information about it on the net are all for windows, did any linux user get this plotter work ?
The tuxplot / cutplot mention this device as working  as parallel peripheral.
Thanks to anyone who point me to the right direction, i followed "plotter no ubunut" tutorial with no results, but should be a lot more software that should be able to make this work.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uC2FBmHh_6Q 
on youtube :"plotter no ubuntu"
on official site you can only get windows driver, but you need to posses the hardware and do the registration of the product this make me feel so constrict !!!

Answer (score 0):

According to product details this plotter speaks HPGL, so the inkcut extension to Inkscape should work.

Just install the plotter via CUPS at localhost:631, as make choose "raw".
The USB connection should show up automatically.
If not, check `lpinfo -v |grep usb:` as they do:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26329186/creating-a-raw-printer-queue-in-cups-host-and-adding-them-through-cups-client

Install the inkcut extension to inkscape

I used this:
http://inkcut.sourceforge.net/

I don't know how it relates to that:
https://github.com/codelv/inkcut

would be interesting, though...

Answer (score -2):

Have some problems vith GCC Expert II. You can try to allow writing to USB:
`sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0`
*ttyUSB0* -  it is port of cutter.
After it need setup plotter as a printer in system setting.

And I've founded some information what about it on russian [here](http://www.sign-forum.ru/viewtopic.php?t=47921)